# Node_modules path corrupt, impossible to commit on GIT

Tags: node.js, git, npm, yeoman

I am trying to keep a version of git of all the components inside node_modules.
I just removed from .gitignore the node_modules folder, I was expecting to sync without any trouble until I get that :

```
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/image-min/node_modules/gifsicle/node_modules/bin-wrapper/node_modules/download/node_modules/decompress/node_modules/adm-zip/package.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
fatal: unable to stat 'node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/image-min/node_modules/gifsicle/node_modules/bin-wrapper/node_modules/download/node_modules/decompress/node_modules/adm-zip/test/assets/attributes_test/New folder/hidden.txt': No such file or directory
```

Git is crashing on this file, that can't be find.

When I use an explorer, there's a mistake on the path :

```
 node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/image-min/node_modules/gifsicle/node_modules/bin-wrapper
```

to

```
 node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/image-min/node_modules/gifsicle/node_modules.bin-wrapper
```

Is there a correct way to push into git without breaking the dependencies ?

Comment: Why use the angularjs tag?

Comment: That's right, just removed it, do you know npm ? maybe you can't help more

Comment: No, I don't. I was browsing the angularjs tag when this came up and I've no idea how to help unfortunately.

Comment: The correct way is not including node_modules folder in the git repository at all. NPM installs required modules by looking at `package.json` file after executing `npm install` command.

Comment: ^What he said. Committing the node_modules directory kind of beats the entire point of using npm

Comment: If the NPM goes down, has apt-get removed one day tomcat 5 from repositoeries, will all my projects gonna ba crashed ?

Comment: if npm goes down packages are cached locally when downloaded.

Comment: @mpm, yeah trust the locally cached for deployed projects, so bad advices sometimes on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the file is a fixture of `adm-zip` package test suite. From it's name (`attributes_test/New folder/hidden.txt`) you can see that this file is somewhat special and can exhibit weird behaviour (and some part of this behaviour is tested, I think). Since git can't handle such a file, the best thing you can do is to add it to `.gitignore` explicitly. It's unlikely that you will encounter such problem with other files or packages.

By the way, including `node_modules` into repository is a standard practice for deployed application (that is, non-libraries). For example, https://github.com/npm/npm-www